# Howto make pyspark use custom python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using zeppelin connect remote spark cluster.

remote spark is using system python 2.7 .

I want to switch to miniconda3, install a lib pyarrow. 
What I do is :

1. Download miniconda3, install some libs, scp miniconda3 folder to spark master and slaves.
2. adding `PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/local/miniconda3/bin/python"` to `spark-env.sh` in spark master and slaves.
3. restart spark and zeppelin
4. Running code

   %spark.pyspark

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf,PandasUDFType


   @pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
   def process_order_items(pdf):

       pdf.loc[:, 'total_price'] = pdf['price'] * pdf['count']

       d = {'has_discount':'count',
           'clearance':'count',
           'count': ['count', 'sum'],
           'price_guide':'max',
           'total_price': 'sum'

       }

       pdf1 = pdf.groupby('day').agg(d)
       pdf1.columns = pdf1.columns.map('_'.join)
       d1 = {'has_discount_count':'discount_order_count',
           'clearance_count':'clearance_order_count',
           'count_count':'order_count',
           'count_sum':'sale_count',
           'price_guide_max':'price_guide',
           'total_price_sum': 'total_price'
       }

       pdf2 = pdf1.rename(columns=d1)

       pdf2.loc[:, 'discount_sale_count'] = pdf.loc[pdf.has_discount>0, 'count'].resample(freq).sum()
       pdf2.loc[:, 'clearance_sale_count'] = pdf.loc[pdf.clearance>0, 'count'].resample(freq).sum()
       pdf2.loc[:, 'price'] = pdf2.total_price / pdf2.sale_count

       pdf2 = pdf2.drop(pdf2[pdf2.order_count == 0].index)

       return pdf2


   results = df.groupby("store_id", "product_id").apply(process_order_items)

   results.select(['store_id', 'price']).show(5)
   ```

Got error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o172.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 143, 10.104.33.18, executor 2): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 230, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 225, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 150, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 276, in load_stream
    import pyarrow as pa
ImportError: No module named pyarrow
```

`10.104.33.18` is spark master,  so I think the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` is not set correctly .

I login to master and slaves, run `pyspark interpreter` in each, and found `import pyarrow` do not throw exception .

PS: `pyarrow` also installed in the machine which running zeppelin.

---

More info:

1. spark cluster is installed in A, B, C , zeppelin is installed in D.
2. `PYSPARK_PYTHON` is set in `spark-env.sh` in each A, B, C
3. `import pyarrow` is fine with `/usr/local/spark/bin/pyspark` in A, B ,C /
4. `import pyarrow` is fine on A, B ,C custom python(miniconda3)
5. `import pyarrow` is fine on D's default python(miniconda3, path is different from A, B ,C , but it is doesn't matter)

So I completely coundn't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to zeppelin configuration folder (*$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf*) and find file *interpreter.json*

Find interpreter you want to fix (spark) in this case.

Update following property to provide path to your python installation:

```
- "zeppelin.pyspark.python": "python"
+ "zeppelin.pyspark.python": "/usr/bin/anaconda/bin/python"
```

Comment: `import pyarrow` is fine on zeppelin with local spark. Only failed with remote spark. `import pyarrow` is fine in remote pyspark. Change "zeppelin.pyspark.python" location which is different from remote spark `PYSPARK_PYTHON`  would only make zeppelin get error .